# MacBook Pro 13 mid 2009 wifi hardware not detected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, macbook, macbook-pro

The question is as the title says. I just installed my optical drive back into it's place, and a few cables got loose (namely the audio and "display" cables). I plugged them back in and switched on the Mac, but it said wifi hardware not detected. Normally one would assume it's a problem with the display cable (which is the cable for Bluetooth, the camera and wifi), but Bluetooth is working perfectly, the camera is functioning, but the wifi icon on the task bar still says the same thing. I ran a system report and refreshed it, and surprisingly the wifi card was being detected there! I reset PRAM and the SMC to no avail. What's going on?

Comment: sounds like your AirPort card is damaged, or the cables are not making proper contact. If PRAM and SMC aren't working, then it is usually a hardware issues.

Sadly, the AirPort card is quite annoying to get to as you have to dissemble the entire computer since the card rests under the clutch cover.

Comment: @MikeDiglio precisely. It seems extra tough to get to the airport card. But I am pretty sure the airport card is okay because I didn't even touch the area it sits in! And this trusty MacBook has never given me any hardware issues, so I am confident the airport card didn't just die. It has to be a cabling error, even though I replugged the Display cable multiple times. Apple support keeps telling me to visit an Authorized Service Provider, but I don't want to unnecessarily spend cash on something that seems like a loose connection. Any suggestions as to what I may have disconnected unknowingly?

Comment: Hmm - The only other thing you can try is booting into Single User Mode (cmd + s) during boot and running "fsck -fy" This will do a file-system check to ensure that your filesystem structure is proper which can cause an issue with hardware not working properly. If that doesn't work, then you will have to resort to dismantling the computer and investigating contact points to ensure they aren't corroded and make sure all cables are making proper contact.